# VBA, Dir Function With Wild Card

Tags: vba, excel

I have a user form that pulls a date to be used in a file path. Within that folder I am attempting to use the Dir function to take a file name as a string. Where it gets tricky is although a portion of the file name is consistent, there is a unique ID at the end that changes day over day so I'm using an asterisk in an attempt to ignore the unique ID portion, and just take the name.

```
Sub cmdRunCO_Click()

Dim masterPathCO As String
Dim masterFileCO As String
Dim DesiredDate As String
' ChDir "\\corp\dfs\appdata\openlinkprod\outdir\US-ComOps\EOD"
' Workbooks.Open Filename:="CHN.Endur.PnlDetailsReport.GLOBAL.US-ComOps.EOD.PV.xlsm"

DesiredDate = EnteredDate.Value & "\"
masterPathCO = "\\corp\dfs\appdata\openlinkprod\outdir\US-ComOps\EOD\" & DesiredDate
maserFileCO = Dir(masterPathCO & "CHN.Endur.PnlDetailsReport.GLOBAL.US-ComOps.EOD.PV.*.xlsm", vbNormal)
' Test for correct string values
Range("A15") = masterPathCO
Range("A16") = masterFileCO
' Dim mwb As Workbook
' Set mwbCO = Workbooks.Open(masterPathCO & masterFileCO)
' Set mwbCO = ActiveWorkbook
Unload SelectDate
```

masterPathCO is fine, however masterFileCO comes out blank. Here is the twist: within the dated folder where I'm attempting to get the file name, there are 3 other files that ALL start with the same name leading me to believe the asterisk isn't actually doing anything.

Alternative, easier method of doing this? Right direction but I'm off somewhere?

Comment: In your code above you have mis-typed one of the variables as `maserFileCO` but have declared and referenced it as `masterFileCO`. I'm not sure if you re-typed the code for this question or not but it would be worth checking your original code for this spelling error.

Comment: `Option Explicit` should be at the top of every module - that will save you from errors like this (assuming not just a typo in your question)

Comment: Goodness... excellent point guys. Incredible how these little things slide past me sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is valid and works without issue.

Problem occurred due to incorrect variable reference, fixed by correcting variable name and ensuring no future issues on this front via Option Explicit statement.